# Make a chrome extension download all PDFs with `declarativeNetRequest`

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have to migrate a chrome extension from MV2 to MV3, and that means replacing usages of the blocking `chrome.webRequest` API with `declarativeNetRequest`. One usage is this:

```js
function enableDownloadPDFListener() {
  chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(downloadPDFListener);
}

function downloadPDFListener(details) {
  const header = details.responseHeaders.find(e => e.name.toLowerCase() === 'content-type');
  if (header.value && header.value === 'application/pdf') {
    const headerDisposition = details.responseHeaders.find(
      e => e.name.toLowerCase() === 'content-disposition'
    );
    if (headerDisposition) {
      headerDisposition.value = headerDisposition.value.replace('inline', 'attachment');
    } else {
      details.responseHeaders.push({ name: 'Content-Disposition', value: 'attachment' });
    }
  }
  return { responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders };
}
```

Explanation: This function intercepts requests, checks if their `Content-Type` header is `application/pdf`, and if that's the case, sets `Content-Disposition: attachment` to force downloading the file. We have this functionality to save our employees time when downloading lots of PDF files from various websites.

The problem I'm facing is that this API is deprecated and can't be used in Manifest V3, and I wasn't able to migrate it to the `declarativeNetRequest` API. I tried the following:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders",
      "responseHeaders": [
        {
          "header": "content-disposition",
          "operation": "set",
          "value": "attachment"
        }
      ]
    },
    "condition": {
      // what should I put here?
    }
  }
]
```

But I don't know how to filter files with a certain `Content-Type` header. From what I understand, this is currently not possible. Is there any other way to get this functionality in Chrome's MV3?

I tried `{ "urlFilter": "*.pdf" }` as a condition, which isn't correct, but might be good enough. However, although the badge indicates that the rule was executed, the `Content-Disposition` header isn't set in the network tab, and the file isn't downloaded. What went wrong here?

Comment: 1) To modify headers you also need host_permissions for the affected URLs e.g. `<all_urls>`. 2) Devtools doesn't show modifications made by DNR.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have set the permission, and I used `chrome.declarativeNetRequest.setExtensionActionOptions({ displayActionCountAsBadgeText: true })` to check if the rule was executed. The badge appeared and then quickly disappeard again.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I don't think there's a condition that would work here. It seems like a reasonable use case and something that may make a good issue at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium though.

In the meantime - could you have an extension which injects a content script that listens to the click event on links? Or alternatively you could perhaps wait for the PDF to open and then close the tab and perform a download.

Comment: Reported [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1414794). I don't think it's possible to download a PDF file from a content script. And while I could add a `download` attribute to all `<a>` elements with a link ending with `.pdf`, I'd need a `MutationObserver` to search for new `<a>` elements on every DOM change, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: A reasonable use case indeed and it was reported long time ago in https://crbug.com/1021672 and https://crbug.com/1141166. Generally you can expect most of things to be already reported, it's just that there's almost no one is working on this API for more than a year, so nothing's changed.